# Intellij idea: TestNg run configuration error. TestNG icons with a cross in the configuration window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I have a selenium project. This project is successfully working on the other pc, but when I open (from zip) this project on the other pc I have the issue with TestNG configuration - I can't start the tests from ide and have the error in the configuration:

[image]

Also, all testng icons have a red cross.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Does it help to select module in "Use classpath" field?

Comment: Similar issues reported - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206168329-IntelliJ-cannot-recognize-the-xml-File-from-Selenium-Test-with-TestNG and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228314?project=IDEA&clearDraft=true&description=%0A%0AIC-193.5233.102,%20JRE%2011.0.4%2B10-b520.11x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o,%20OS%20Windows%2010(amd64)%20v10.0%20,%20screens%203840x2160

Comment: in my case it was just error on ui, otherwise tests are running.

Comment: @y.bedrov No, the same result

Comment: @NarendranSolaiSridharan, thanks. I have launched tests already, however, the icon has the same image... I even load the project into a third PC with the same IntelliJ idea version and all work well there :)